# TYPO3 how can I use a complex mysql statement in a TCA displayCond

Tags: mysql, typo3, backend

is there anyway to use a mysql Statement in a displayCondition of TCA?

Something like this:

```
'displayCond' => 'SELECT flag from mysecondtable where id = 123',
```

Regards
n00n

Answer (score 4):

Not directly, but you can make a function in a class and use that as a userFunc See: [TCA documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/stable/Reference/Columns/#displaycond)

As you can see in the documentation you can pass parameters to your function to do any complex checks that you want.

Comment: Yeah, heard about it, ... thought there could be an easier way. Hod not really a chance to get into userFunc's...